# Negative integral of a positive function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs

fixed in **10.1** (windows)

---

For a parameter $t\in (0,1)$

```
$Assumptions = t ∈ Reals && t > 0 && t < 1
```

I define an obviously positive function $f(x)=\left| \Re \left(\frac{\exp(ix)}{1-t\exp(ix)}\right)\right|$

```
f[x_] = Abs[Re[Exp[I*x]/(1 - t*Exp[I*x])]]
```

Mathematica 9.0.1.0 calculates the integral

```
Integrate[f[x], {x, 0, 2 π}]
```

as $-2 \pi /t$ which is negative. What is the problem?

Comment: This definitely looks like a bug that should be reported. In version 8.0.4 the integral stays unevaluated, which is better than giving a wrong result...

Comment: Forgot to mention that in v10 the result is the same as in v9.

Comment: Reported as a bug.

Comment: What is it that much hard for MMA developers to fix this bug between version 9 and 10? They could at the least put a message to warn about the bug.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As you notniced, the result is not correct.  This is not uncommon with *definite* integrals, as the system needs to detect any special behaviour inbetween the integration bounds, which is hard.  **For this reason it's a good idea to verify such integrals numerically.**

We can get the correct result like this (please evaluate in a fresh kernel without `$Assumptions`).

First, for numerical verification:

```
F[t_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[ Abs@Re[Exp[I*x]/(1 - t*Exp[I*x])], {x, 0, 2Pi} ]

Plot[F[t], {t, -5, 5}, MaxRecursion -> 2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We see that it has a different behaviour for $-1 < t < 1$ than for $|t| > 1$.  That's because the integrand, without the `Abs`, changes sign in $[0, 2\pi]$ when $|t| < 1$:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Re[Exp[I*x]/(1 - t*Exp[I*x])], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotRange -> All],
 {t, -2, 2}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Mathematica managed to get the correct result this way:

```
fun = Re[Exp[I*x]/(1 - t*Exp[I*x])] // ComplexExpand // Simplify
(* (-t + Cos[x])/(1 + t^2 - 2 t Cos[x]) *)

Integrate[Abs[fun], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Assumptions -> 0 < t < 1]
(* (π - ArcCos[t] + I ArcCosh[t] + 
 2 ArcTan[(-1 + t)/Sqrt[1 - t^2]] - 
 2 ArcTan[((1 + t) Tan[ArcCos[t]/2])/(-1 + t)])/t *)

res = FullSimplify[%, 0 < t < 1]
(* ((3 π)/2 + I ArcCosh[t] + ArcSin[t] + 
 4 ArcTan[(-1 + t)/Sqrt[1 - t^2]])/t *)
```

Then verify numerically:

```
Table[res - F[t], {t, 0, 1, .1}] // Chop

{Indeterminate, -5.7728*10^-7, -1.70775*10^-7, -1.8055*10^-6, -8.52578*10^-8, 
 7.67182*10^-8, -5.98418*10^-7, -1.16494*10^-6, -7.9843*10^-7, 
 4.67139*10^-7, Indeterminate}
```

It agrees with the numerical calculation up to a small numerical error.

Alternatively, we might try to find where `fun == 0` and manually piece the integral together from two parts where `fun > 0` and `fun < 0`.  Then we don't need to rely on `Integrate` being able to handle this simplified `Abs[fun]`.  I can show how on request.

Comment: Yes, please show it to us, +1.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I find it strange that the simple explicit calculation of the real part changes the result. Moreover, the "pseudo-complex" expresseion $i$ ArcCosh$(t)$ (which is in fact real for an appropriate definition of ArcCosh) is strange.

Comment: @JochenWengenroth I managed to get a simpler expression `(2/t) (Pi - 2 ArcCos[t])` by doing it half-manually.

Comment: @Szabolcs Excellent!

Answer (score 2):

Just a workaround.

```
In[4]:= Clear["Global`*"]

In[5]:= f[x_, t_] := Abs[Re[Exp[I*x]/(1 - t*Exp[I*x])]]

In[6]:= Timing[
 resAn[t_] = 
  Integrate[f[x, EulerGamma], {x, 0, 2*Pi}] /. EulerGamma -> t]

Out[6]= {23.104, -((2*(ArcCos[t] + 
        2*ArcTan[((1 + t)*Tan[ArcCos[t]/2])/(-1 + t)]))/t)}

In[7]:= resNum[t_] := NIntegrate[f[x, t], {x, 0, 2*Pi}]

In[8]:= (resNum[#1] - resAn[#1] & ) /@ RandomReal[{0, 1}, 10]

Out[8]= {-2.700923671383748*^-7, 2.0563655223071464*^-7, \
-5.813341690696916*^-6, 
   1.2717096442571574*^-6, 2.194853188086654*^-8, \
3.578415519456257*^-7, 
   -7.5046305703097*^-7, -2.2693759706982064*^-6, \
1.3046701408114814*^-7, 
   6.545158557358377*^-7}
```

**Update**

Proceeding a little further and in view of Szalbocs' last comment I managed to get a simplified answer as follows

```
In[117]:= Timing[
 Integrate[
  Abs[Re[Exp[I*x]/(1 - t*Exp[I*x])]] /. t -> EulerGamma, {x, 0, 2*Pi}]]

Out[117]= {19.15692280000000025097506295423954725266`7.302925662369298, 
   -((2*(ArcCos[EulerGamma] + 
        2*ArcTan[((1 + EulerGamma)*Tan[ArcCos[EulerGamma]/2])/(-1 + 
             EulerGamma)]))/EulerGamma)}

In[131]:= FullSimplify[
 TrigToExp[-((2*(ArcCos[EulerGamma] + 
         2*ArcTan[((1 + EulerGamma)*Tan[ArcCos[EulerGamma]/2])/(-1 + 
              EulerGamma)]))/EulerGamma)]]
(FullSimplify[#1, 0 < u < Pi/2] & )[% /. EulerGamma -> Cos[u]]
FullSimplify[% /. u -> ArcCos[EulerGamma]] /. EulerGamma -> t

Out[131]= (Pi + 
   2*ArcCot[(2*EulerGamma*Sqrt[1 - EulerGamma^2])/(-1 + 
        2*EulerGamma^2)])/EulerGamma

Out[132]= (Pi + 2*ArcCot[Tan[2*u]])*Sec[u]

Out[133]= (4*ArcSin[t])/t
```

Comment: What is the moral of the replacement t-> EulerGamma?

Comment: N@EulerGamma -> 0.577216  and  0<t<1 as it mentioned in the begining of the post.

Comment: Of course I do not consider this method as a panacea for each and every simular situation. As I said it is just a workaround. Nothing more, nothing less. At least, it provides a solution:-)! Obviously, Szalbocs analysis is more rigorous.

Answer (score 1):

fixed in **10.1** (windows).

Now integral remains unevaluated.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

[image: Mathematica graphics]

code:

```
$Assumptions = t \[Element] Reals && t > 0 && t < 1
f[x_] = Abs[Re[Exp[I*x]/(1 - t*Exp[I*x])]]
Integrate[f[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]
```